# how can we perform zip operation in databricks using python or anyway?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Geeting a below error
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported.
The error occurs when trying to append files  to a zip file from both Python and R, scala.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you're trying to modify file on DBFS. The problem is that there are [limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations) when you work with files on DBFS via local API (the `/dbfs` fuse).  For example, it doesn't support random writes that are required for ZIP files.  From documentation:

> Does not support random writes. For workloads that require random writes, perform the I/O on local disk first and then copy the result to `/dbfs`.

Your code could be (copy file to local disk, perform modification, copy file back):

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("your_file_on_dbfs", "file:/tmp/temp-file.zip")
... perform append
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/temp-file.zip", "your_file_on_dbfs")
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your answer. but it is not working for in my case.

Comment: What doesn’t work? Any specific error?