# GDAL error while saving raster in Databricks

Tags: r, databricks, raster

I am trying to save a raster on databrick notebook but I get:

```
terra::writeRaster(r, 'test.tif'))

Warning: _tiffSeekProc:Operation not supported (GDAL error 1)
Warning: TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data (GDAL error 1)
.
.
.
.
Warning: _tiffWriteProc:Operation not supported (GDAL error 1)
Warning: _tiffSeekProc:Operation not supported (GDAL error 1)
Warning: _tiffSeekProc:Operation not supported (GDAL error 1)
Warning: TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data (GDAL error 1)
Warning: _tiffSeekProc:Operation not supported (GDAL error 1)
Warning: TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data (GDAL error 1)
Warning: I/O error (GDAL error 3)
```

Comment: see here for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360641/18627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the same problem as reported [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1189). That is, you need random file access to write a Tiff file, but your connection only supports sequential writing.